# What is the best place to learn how to code arbitrage flash loans?

Tags: flash-loans

This I already know: flash loans are given and paid in the same transaction, possibly to sell on one exchange and buy on the other.

As you might or not know, I pasted someone else’s code in a separate thread here in stackexchange in the past in hopes of fixing any errors. However, you guys said I should be making my own code from scratch instead of being taken advantage of by someone else’s code and robbed of my money unless it’s 100% understood.

So I looked at like a 17-minute Solidity tutorial from YouTube, and then realized the longer tutorials weren’t really teaching how to make flash loans. So I figured that flash loan videos were the answer. But what they do is walk through codes other people made, which you do not want me to use.

So what do I do? I’m not even sure, so here I am. Please help.

Comment: I said please help! Are you going to or not?